# Regex Fine End of Search Field then remove rest of line

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

Hi I have been looking for a Regex I can find most of what im after but not quite right.

Im trying to do a find a replace using regex, which i can get to work but not quite the way i want to.

An example of what i am searching is

---

10/01/14PUT/a/users/84335httpetcetcetcete

10/01/14GET/a/users/663/badges?thisisatest

10/01/14GET/a/users/8836:thisisatestetc

---

What im trying to do is and the end of the user digits as shown below by a % i have put in temporarily i want to remove the rest of the line.

---

10/01/14PUT/a/users/84335%httpetcetcetcete

10/01/14GET/a/users/663%/badges?thisisatest

10/01/14GET/a/users/8836%:thisisatestetc

---

I have been using s = s.regex.replace(s, "a/users/\d*", " ")

but this if obviously not working, so close yet so far.

Any assistance is gratefully received.

Many thanks, VBVirg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were actually on the right track, the regex you came up with is almost what you need:

```
a/users/\d*
```

But what your call did was actually replace what you wanted to preserve with a space.

The regex you're looking for would be more like this:

```
(a\/users\/\d*).*$
```

And you would use it in the `Replace()` method as follows:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "(a\/users\/\d*).*$", "$1") />
```

The `$1` is a backreference to the capture group (the part of the regex in parentheses). So what this would do is take whatever part of the string matches that regex, and replace it with only what is in the capture group.

Comment: If you're sure that at least one user digit will be in the string, you can use `\d+` instead of `\d*` above.

Answer (score 1):

How about: `s = s.regex.replace(s, "(a/users/\d*).*", "\1")`

This will save the "a/users/(digits)" string to a variable (`\1`), so it doesn't get deleted by the `replace` function.

Comment: Brilliant thank you so so much, i was going out of my tiny mind, and thank you everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following will do what you want:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, "^(.*\/users\/\d*).*$", "$1")
```

It works by capturing the part of the string you are interested in and replacing the whole string with just the part that was captured.